# ASP.NET MVC Redirect to Home Page from Error Page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to redirect to home page on click of banner.
But it is not working as expected.
Error occured on 'Work' controller.
Error Page showed up as expected on exception, but on click of banner it redirects to

```
http://127.0.0.1:81/Error?aspxerrorpath=/Work/Home
```

Javascript used:

```
function redirectToHome() {
        var page = 'Home';
        window.location = page;
    }
```

It works from any other page , but not from error page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Home", "Login")';
            window.location.href = url;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this,

```
function redirectToHome() {
        var page = '/Home';
      window.location.href=page
  }
```